# How to instantiate derived classes without having to rewrite code?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Let's say I have a:

```
class A {
    A(int i);
};

class B : A {
};
```

I cannot instanciate B(3) for instance, as this constructor is not defined. Is there a way to instanciate a B object that would use the A constructor, without having to add "trivial" code in all derived classes? thanks

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++11 has a way:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int i);
};

class B : A {
public:
    using A::A; // use A's constructors
};
```

Comment: For completeness: and it's impossible in C++03.

Comment: Weehoo. I didn't realize constructor forwarding enabled that. +1 This is sweet for template meta-programming too

Comment: @Pubby8: that must be the reason I hadn't found out yet!

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++03 this is the best thing I can think of in your situation:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int x) { ... }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(int x) : A(x) { ... }
}
```

You may also want to check out the link below, which is a C# question but contains a more detailed answer regarding why constructors can act this way:

[C# - Making all derived classes call the base class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296888/c-sharp-making-all-derived-classes-call-the-base-class-constructor)

Answer (score 2):

as  user491704 said
it should be something like this

```
class mother {
public:
 mother (int a)
 {}
 };

class son : public mother {
public:
 son (int a) : mother (a)
 { }
   };
```

[Here is a link for the Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/)