# Why won't this child class instantiate

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent(string someArg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent");
    }

}

class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string someArg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Child");
    }
}
```

which I then instantiate:

```
var child = new Child("something");
```

gets me an error. I know it has to do with the parent constructor, but I'm not sure why is this the case. Am I required to use `base` every time I have a constructor in the parent which is not parameter-less? Why?

Comment: Please state what error is returned.

Comment: change it to `public Child(string someArg):base(someArg)` to call the constructor of the parent class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - Making all derived classes call the base class constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296888/c-sharp-making-all-derived-classes-call-the-base-class-constructor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The base class needs initialization just as well. Therefore, when the base class only has a constructor with an appetite for parameters, you will have to feed it.

In this case, if you are overriding everything the baseclass constructor does, you could let the baseclass have a second, parameterless, constructor. And  if you'd like to make use of the logic in the baseclass constructor, you really have no choice but to call `: base(string)`

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a class it has a default parameterless constructor. If you define your own construct then default one is **gone**. In your case you defined a constructor with a parameter.

When you create a new instance each class in inheritance hierarchy should be constructed. Base class has the only constructor with a string parameter which is not called in your code. The implicit parameterless constructor call cannot happen as well.

So that's why you should white:

```
public Child(string someArg) :base(someArg) { }
```

Or you can bring the parameterless constructor back in you code and do not use `base`:

```
public Parent() { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this at base class to solve your problem.

```
public Parent() {}
```

or make it protected to use it just for child classes

```
protected Parent() {}
```