# Shorthand for derived constructor just passing to base

Tags: c#, syntax, constructor, derived-class

*** NOT THIS QUESTION: [Calling the base constructor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp?rq=1) ***

---

I know how to call `this` or `base` to chain constructors.

Even so, occasionally I end up with a base constructor with many parameters, and a derived class which doesn't change the constructor at all. (All the derived class is doing is changing some of the implementation details of virtual methods.) When that happens I still have to define the derived constructor and pass all the params through to the base constructor.

**Question: Is there any syntax sugar that says "this class doesn't declare it's own constructor, it uses an exact replica of the base constructor."**

---

No doubt the number of params is a CodeSmell, and I should try to fix that or create a ParamObject to hold them all,but that's not the topic of the question.

There are many other ways that I could solve this problem, I'm interested in specifically whether a syntax exists to let me solve it *that* way.

Comment: This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296937/1662268 suggests the answer is probably "No".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No - constructors are not inherited, and there's no syntax to "automagically" call base constructors that have the same parameters.