# What does it mean to "override" the ctor of ServiceBase?

Tags: c#, constructor, windows-services

I have recently started working with winservices and I stumbled upon [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceProcess_ServiceBase__ctor) about winservice ctor and it talks about "overriding" the ServiceBase constructor.
Feeling stupid i googled what that means and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271920/is-it-possible-to-override-a-constructor-in-c).
Question: What do they *actually* mean by saying "overriding" in the docs?To chain back explicitly to a ServiceBase ctor?

Comment: The documentation is a bit misleading. It simply means to provide a constructor for your new class. A constructor is not virtual, so you cannot override it (a word that already has a meaning in the C# language).

Comment: It's very poor phrasing of a *general* rule in .NET. That if you have any constructors in your class, you have to ensure they chain back to a constructor in your base class. Since this class only has one constructor, there aren't many choices of which constructor to chain back to. (Insert all standard defaults around `:object` and `base()`). So I'm not sure why they called it out at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really agree with what MS says. `ServiceBase` has an empty default constructor which will automatically be called so the statement that you have to override it (which is not true as well, I'd be *overloading* instead of *overriding*) is not really true.
However, what I *guess* they meant is to call the base constructor like this

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase {
    public MyService(var something) : base(){

    }
}
```

which is the same as

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase {
    public MyService(var something){

    }
}
```

/edit: In theory, if you'd *overload* (not override) the base constructor, you'll have to explicitly call it.

```
public class ServiceBase{
    public ServiceBase(){

    }

    public ServiceBase(var something) {

    }
}
```

```
public class MyService : ServiceBase {
    public MyService(var something)
        : base(something) 
    {

    }
}
```

However, overloading the `ServiceBase` constructor is not possible because the class is not marked as `partial`.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose they just wanted to tell us to do the "minimum" ("The minimum you need to implement in the constructor for a class inherited from ServiceBase is to set the ServiceName on your component.") which I actually do not do.

Answer (score 0):

MS just states that you should call the base constructor if you derive from ServiceBase (like this)

```
class MyService:ServiceBase
public MyService : base() {
.. custom code ..
}
```

This will call the base constructor in addition to your new .ctor.
Have a look here for "overriding" .ctor:
[C# - Making all derived classes call the base class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296888/c-sharp-making-all-derived-classes-call-the-base-class-constructor)