# How can I instantitate a list based on the specific object type?

Tags: c#, oop

I have the following definitions:

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
    ...
    public BaseEntity()
    {

    }
}

public class KeyValuePair
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
    public string meta;
}

public class KeyValuePairList : BaseEntity
{
    public List<KeyValuePair> List {set; get;}

    public KeyValuePairList(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> list)
    {
        this.List = new List<KeyValuePair>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair k in list) {
            this.List.Add(k);
        }
    }
}
```

I have 10 more different classes like `KeyValuePair` and `KeyValuePairList` all achieving the same purpose - the former defines the object, the latter defines the list into which these objects should be placed. How can I incorporate this functionality into the base class `BaseEntity` so that I don't have to redefine the List instantiation logic in each individual class i.e. I want to be able to instantiate the list based on the object type being passed to the constructor? Any suggestions?

Comment: You have second `BaseEntity` class defined within the `BaseEntity` class?  I don't think that's even possible. **EDIT** I think you meant that to be the constructor, right?

Comment: @Kevin: I assume that it's a typo, omit the `class` and you get a constructor.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes. Sorry! I was typing a simpler example looking at my IDE. Edited the question now.

Comment: How do your KeyValuePair classes differ? If they are all related in some way, could you not use a generic type parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you use generics?

```
public class BaseEntity<T> where T: class
{
    public List<T> List { set; get; }

    public BaseEntity(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        this.List = new List<T>();
        foreach (T k in list)
        {
            this.List.Add(k);
        }
    }
}

public class KeyValuePair
{
    public string key;
    public string value;
    public string meta;
}

public class KeyValuePairList : BaseEntity<KeyValuePair>
{
    public KeyValuePairList(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair> list) 
        : base(list) { }
}
```

Comment: +1 Awesome. Thank you. I was moving towards that approach after I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp and now I have your answer as well. Thank you for your time.