# Exception that throws another Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

I have a `CustomException` class, that is a wrapper on top of `Exception` class. This is the main class that i use when i handle Exceptions.

```
public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }
    public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; private set; }

    public CustomException(string errorMessage)
        : this(errorMessage, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    { }

    public CustomException(string message, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
    {
        ErrorMessage = message;
        HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

When i want to throw an exception, i use `throw CustomException()` method.

However, i want to create some wrappers on top of this CustomException() as well, for example:

```
public class ApplicationNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public ApplicationNotFoundException(Application application)
    {
        string message = string.Format(@"Application ""{0}"" was not found", application.ApplicationName);
        throw new CustomException(message, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

And i throw exception line this: `throw new ApplicationNotFoundException(application)`

Basically i am throwing an Exception from another Exception.

Is this approach bad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically not the approach to use `exceptions`.
Creating custom `exceptions` serves your custom needs, that if built-in exceptions can't handle this.
There are some ways for you:

1. Create a hierarchy of exceptions, where `CustomException` is your "base" class and `ApplicationNotFoundException` is a derived one, this is the preferred way of specializing.

or

1. Embed the information you need into your custom exception-classes (create small `struct`s if you just want to send some information and don't need to work on the particular objects themselves)

**EDIT**

Also, which is very important, consider `stack unwinding` as a factor of efficiency. Throwing an exception forces the call stack to be unwound, which takes a little time, too!

You can do it your way, of course, but it might tighten things a little up, which could be unnecessary.

For some background, consider [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx).

Comment: +1, ApplicationNotFoundException should derive from CustomException

Comment: @bash.d: The only downside of having `ApplicationNotFoundException` deriving from `CustomException` is that i cannot create the exception text inside the body of `ApplicationNotFoundException` constructor

Comment: @RaraituL You can't?? Why not??

Comment: @bash.d I've just seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp). It looks like i can do it after all

Comment: @RaraituL See, everything is fine! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let the user of your `ApplicationNotFoundException` decide when it is appropriate to throw.
Don't do it in the constructor of your ApplicationNotFoundException.

Instead derive your ApplicationNotFoundException from CustomException

```
public class ApplicationNotFoundException : CustomException 
{
    public ApplicationNotFoundException(Application application)
    {
        string message = string.Format(@"Application '{0}' was not found", application.ApplicationName);
        base.ErrorMessage = message
        base.HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
    }
}

public class CustomException : Exception
{
    public string ErrorMessage { get; internal set; }
    public HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode { get; internal set; }

    public CustomException(string errorMessage)
        : this(errorMessage, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    { }

    public CustomException(string message, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
    {
        ErrorMessage = message;
        HttpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: This means i first initialize the `ApplicationNotFoundException` class, then i throw it?

Comment: Yes, when you need to throw the exception you call `throw new ApplicationException(appInstance);`

Answer (score 1):

A common scenario is to **rethrow** your more specific exception type rather in the catch block than in the constructor:

```
try {
    ... // Try to find application
}
catch(ApplicationNotFoundException ex) {
    var message = ...;
    throw new CustomException(message, HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
}
```

When rethrowing a different exception, you can set the InnerException property with the original exception to aid debugging.