# Passing parameters to the base class constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters, abstract

If the base class and derived class both have their constructors with parameters then where we pass the parameters to the base class constructors?

Comment: This is a duplicate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp

Googling "base class constructor parameters" would have brought it right to you.

Comment: You say "you can't instantiate an abstract class," but that's not entirely true.  If you create an instance of the non-abstract derived class, that instance is also an instance of the abstract base class.  It is also an instance of the System.Object class.

Comment: FYI, even if it's an `abstract` class, it can have defined custom constructors with parameters that can be passed in. They can't be instantiated/called _directly_ but instead are referenced in derived types by using the [`base` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) with the derived constructors.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Like this:

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(int derivedParam, String baseParam):base(baseParam)
    {
    }
}
```

The `base` keyword here calls the base class constructor that matches the provided parameter overload.

Comment: Is the default constructor still invoked if base constructor is called as `:base(param)` ?

Comment: No. That constructor would have to call `this()` @Ahmn21