# How to access a class with protected constructor from another class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, parameters

I have a class with protected constructor. Is there any possibilities to access this class from another class

Base Class :

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
    private static ClassA _classA = new ClassA();
    private static ClassB _classB= new ClassB();
    protected BaseClass(ClassA _classA, ClassB _classB)
    {
        _classA = classA;
        _classB= classB;
    }
```

This is my Derived Class :

```
    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {

    }
```

Derived class require to pass parameter. How to solve it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing parameters to the base class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481456/passing-parameters-to-the-base-class-constructor)

Comment: Are you sure your `BaseClass` looks like that? It is **very** odd to have an instance constructor that overwrites `static` variables like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(ClassA classA, ClassB classB) : base(classA, classB)
    {

    }
}
```