# Inheriting Constructors in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, inheriting-constructors

For context, I got this code from [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/gB1F9G0JXOo), particularly at 2:27:28.

I have two classes, `Player` and `Warrior`. I want the `Warrior` class to inherit from the `Player` class. The `Player` class looks like this:

```
public class Player: MonoBehaviour
{
    //Variables and Properties
    private string _playerName;
    public string pName { get => _playerName; set => _playerName = value; }

    private int _playerHealth;
    public int Health { get => _playerHealth ; set => _playerHealth = value ; }

    private int _playerPower;
    public int Power { get => _playerPower; set => _playerPower = value ; }


    //Constructors
    public Player() { } //Constructor 1

    public Player(string name, int health, int power) //Constructor 2
    {
        pName = name;
        Health = health;
        Power = power;
    }
}
```

And the `Warrior` class looks like this:

```
public class Warrior : Player
{
    public Warrior(string name, int health, int power)
    {
        pName = name;
        Health = health;
        Power = power;
    }
}
```

Whenever I remove Constructor 1 in `Player` (the blank one), I get an error in the Warrior constructor. But if I remove the `Warrior` Constructor itself, then I get an error when declaring the `Warrior` class itself. I don't understand why it would be necessary to add Constructor 1, especially when I already have Constructor 2 in the `Player` class, to begin with.

Is there something I am missing? Or does a parent class always need an extra constructor whenever the child is being declared? And if so, Why? Or maybe inheriting constructors in UNITY works differently?

I tried removing Constructor 1 and using the command **`CTRL + .`** in VS, and even the debugger confuses me. I also tried googling online to no avail.

Comment: `Player` defines `pName`, `Health`, and `Power`, so `Warrior`'s constructor should pass the parameters that are assigned to them to `Player`'s constructor (you've labeled it "Constructor 2"). The derived class shouldn't take responsibility for initializing the base class.

Comment: `Player`'s "Constructor 1" (the *default constructor*) shouldn't exist because `Player` shouldn't ever be instantiated without being given values to initialize its properties.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481456/passing-parameters-to-the-base-class-constructor

Comment: I haven't looked at the tutorial you're referencing but you're not supposed to use constructors *at all* in `MonoBehaviour`.

Comment: Ugh... `MonoBehaviour`... that thing needs to come with a warning label.

Comment: in addition to @madreflection first comment: You should/would usually also no go through the properties in the constructor but rather set the fields ... except in your case you could even use auto-properties

Comment: @rshepp Oh... so I just can't, or rather shouldn't, use constructors in unity? But rather the Awake(), OnEnable(), and Start() methods by manually assigning values to properties in them?

Comment: You can use constructors in the classes you create if they don't derive from a Unity object, e.g., `MonoBehaviour`, `ScriptableObject`, etc. The engine handles construction of these objects. Instead of writing `Player player = new Player();`, you would write `GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab);`. If the object's initialization depends on whatever spawned it, then you could write a public `Init(value1, value2, etc)` method to allow the spawner to provide some initialization values after instantiation. If the object can initialize itself, you can use Unity events like Start, etc.

Comment: @rshepp One last question. Do you think I should reformat/reword my question to ask more so about Constructors in Unity? And if so, how do you think I should go about it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like rshepp said, you probably shouldn't use constructors with MonoBehaviors. Instead, use Start() and Awake() to initialize.

Comment: While I agree with you, it would have also been useful to answer the question since not all classes in Unity are MonoBehaviours.