# Having a contructor extend into a sub-class from an abstract class?

Tags: c#, abstract-class, instantiation

I currently have an abstract class such as

```
abstract class Users
{
    private List<string> SelectedUsers;

    public Users(List<string> SelectedUsers)
    {
        this.SelectedUsers = SelectedUsers;
    }
}
```

and a sub-class

```
class UsersTypeOne : Users
{
     //What do I put here in order to call the constructor in the abstract class
}
```

Comment: Here is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you, I have finally found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class UsersTypeOne : Users
{
    public UsersTypeOne(List<string> SelectedUsers)
        : base(SelectedUsers)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you so much for such a quick response

Comment: @LukaszTheCoder: Kindly accept the answer by clicking on the check mark on the upper-left corner of this answer once you are able to **if this answered your question**. This is how we say thanks here in Stack Overflow. :)