# Create instance of Class using Activator with parameter-less constructor in base class

Tags: c#

I have a base class with many descendants. In the base class a parameter-less constructor is declared. Descendants may declare specialized constructors.

```
public class A 
{
   public A()
   {
   }
}

public class B : A
{
  string Stuff { get; set; }
  public B(string stuff)
  {
    Stuff = stuff;
  }
}
```

At some point I want to instantiate a B using the Activator. This instance needs no initialization of it's "Stuff". So I want to use the A's default constructor:

```
public object InstantiateType(Type type)
{
   return Activator.CreateInstance(
      type,
      BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
      BindingFlags.Public |
      BindingFlags.NonPublic
   );
}
```

This sample call results in an exception as many other variations on this theme, is it at all possible, and if so how do I instruct the Activator to do so?

Comment: public B() : base() {}

Comment: You can't bypass a missing constructor. You could use `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` but then the `A` constructor wouldn't be called.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-base-constructor-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround for you:

```
public class A {
    ///<summary>Creates an instance of A, or of a subclass of A</summary>
    public static A Create<T>() where T : A {
        A result = (A)FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(T));
        result.defaultInit();
        return result;
    }

    public A() {
        defaultInit();
    }

    private void defaultInit() {
        // field assignments ...
        // default constructor code ...
    }
}

public class B : A {
    string Stuff { get; set; }
    public B(string stuff) {
        Stuff = stuff;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this, as the default constructor doesn't perform any work, If it works the green tick is for you

Comment: It works even without the default init. I needed an instance to invoke a method that builds some delegates. No data is used. For normal use it would not be very safe according to the documentation, and implementing a defaultinit in each class would be no better than adding a constructor, but for this your out of the box answer is great!

Answer (score 3):

> At some point I want to instantiate a B using ... A's default constructor

You can't.  Constructors aren't inherited, and there is no parameterless constructor for `B` that you can use.  You will need to create a constructur that passes through to the base constructor:

```
public class B : A
{
  string Stuff{get;set}
  public B(string stuff)
  {
    Stuff = stuff;
  }
  public B() : base()  // technically the ": base()" is redundant since A only has one constructor
  {
  }
}
```

You could also change your `CreateInstance` call to pass in `null` as the string parameter.

Comment: I have a lot of descendants, and they declare different constructors. I could add a parameter less constructor to all sub classes, but this is the thing I'm trying to avoid

Comment: Try all you want, but you can't call constructors that don't exist.

Comment: After defining a parameterized constructor the default constructor is not generated.

Comment: So the answer is: No you can't. Thanks

Comment: @k.c. Correct.  I've edited my answer to make that more clear.  Sorry if it was ambiguous before.