# Issue related to Parameterized Constructor in Base Class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have some confusion regarding constructor when inheritance is used:

i have following code :

```
 class Program 
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassD obj = new ClassD(10);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class ClassA
    {
        public ClassA(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Constructor of ClassA");
        }
    }
    class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        public ClassB(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parameterized Constructor of ClassB");
        }
    }
    class ClassC : ClassB
    {
        public ClassC(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parameterized Constructor of ClassC");
        }
    }
    class ClassD : ClassC 
    {
        public ClassD(int a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parameterized Constructor of ClassD");
        }
    }
```

when i write above code.. compiler generated 3 error saying :

```
'ClassA' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  

'ClassB' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments  

'ClassC' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

so why these errors throwing ?? 
is it necessary to have default constructor in base class.

what if i dont want default constructor in base class but want to have default constructor in derived class ?

Comment: Why is this tagged both C# and C++ it can't be both.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12051/440558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so why these errors throwing ??

It's not throwing errors. The compiler is showing compilation errors. It's doing this because there isn't a default constructor on the base class and your derived classes are calling the base class with the parameter it requires.

> is it necessary to have default constructor in base class.

No.

> what if i dont want default constructor in base class but want to have default constructor in derived class ?

Then you provide a default constructor in the derived class but it must still call the base class and provide the parameters required by the base class constructor.

```
public ClassB() : base(0) // Or whatever value you want here for this default constructor
```