# Custom Exception: customize message before call the base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, custom-exceptions

I defined this custom exception

```
public class ThirdPartyServiceException : System.Exception
{
    public ThirdPartyServiceException(string message, Exception innerException): base(message, innerException)
    { }
}
```

That's fine, but now I want customize the exception message before call the base constructor. Something like:

```
public class ThirdPartyServiceException : System.Exception
{
    public ThirdPartyServiceException(string code, string message, string description, Exception innerException)
    {
        base(string.format("Error: {0} - {1} | {2}", code, message, description), innerException) 
    }
}
```

But I can't call the base constructor in this way. So how I can do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling the base constructor in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ThirdPartyServiceException : System.Exception
{
    public ThirdPartyServiceException(string code, string message, string description, Exception innerException)
    :base(string.format("Error: {0} - {1} | {2}", code, message, description), innerException) 
    {        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Override the `Message` property.

Comment: @MathieuF - I disagree, I think this is the best way to customise the exception message: insisting that it be done by passing to the base constructor is a classic example of the XY problem.