# Class to inherit the constructor of its base class

Tags: c#-4.0

I would like to know if I can access  the constructor of the base class in its derived classes in C#. If yes please let me know how could we make it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling the base constructor in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You can call the base class constructor as part of the execution of the derived class constructor

```
public MyBase
{
    public MyBase() { }
}

public Derived
{
    public Derived() : base() { }
}
```

When using this pattern, you are said to be using the base class initializer.

For more background, see the [base keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx) and [instance constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx) on MSDN.