# Constructor in C#

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a parent class with 2 constructor and the derived class trying to call the constructor of parent in 2 different methods

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        //some stuffs
    }
    public Parent(string st)
    {
        //some stuffs
    }
}
```

Now I have a derived class with two methods.
I Have to use `Parent`-constructor in one method and the `Parent(string st)` in other method.
But here It is always calling the `Parent`-constructor. Below is the derived class

```
public class Derived : Parent
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        //Here I initialize the constructor like this
        Parent p = new Parent();
    }

    public void GetData1()
    {
        string s = "1";
        Parent p = new Parent(s);
    }
}
```

Please let me how to make this happen.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not inheriting Parent, you're creating an instance. See how to call the parent constructor here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why do you create a new instance it all? You have already one, yourself. If yu made `GetData` static it would be a factory method that returns an instance. But currently it's pointless.

Comment: @steenbergh Tim is right, your code as is, is pointless to derive from `Parent`, but you code does call constructor overload that takes a string. Why do you think it doesn't? Put a `Console.WriteLine` in that constructor, you'll see it works.

Answer (score 5):

Just have two constructors in your Derived class that use the appropriate constructor in the base.

```
public class Derived : Parent
{
   public Derived() : base()
   {
   }

   public Derived(string s) : base(s)
   {
   }
}
```

The `:base()` nomenclature will invoke the parent constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Use the parent constructor call "base"

```
public class Parent {
   public Parent() {}
   public Parent(string s) {}
```

}

```
public class Child : Parents {
   public Child():base() // Call Parent empty constructor

   public Child(string s): base(s) // Call Parent Constructor with parameter
}
```

Your error comes because you're instanciate a new Object Parents in your Child.
With Base(), you call the parent constructor without instanciate him.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `new Derived()` will call the Parent() ctor because it inherits from Parent and has an implicit `Derived() : base()`.

After you have constructed `Derived()` calling the method (not constructor) `GetData1()` will call the `Parent(string st)` constructor

These are completely separate routes of constructing parent and it seem you are confusing them

Answer (score 1):

The `Parent()` constructor is always called because you Derived derives from `Parent` but doesnt include a constructor, hence a `default constructor` is created, which calls the parameterless `parent constructor`.

The call to `Parent p = new Parent(s);` will call the constructor of `Parent` that takes a parameter.

If you want to call the `parent constructor` when creating a `Derived` object, you have to chain the constructors using `base()`.

```
public class Derived : Parent
{
   public void Derived()
    : base()
   {
       //code
   }

   public void Derived(string s)
        :base(s)
   {
       //code
   }
}
```