# Why am I able to use the no void or return value on this function

Tags: unity-game-engine, inheritance

Hey I was wondering why can I use a function with no return value "void". But if I make a function that has same name as the script name I can make a function can anyone please clarify this?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Parameters  {


    public Parameters()
    {
//why am I able to make this function
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructor in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693253/constructor-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function defined like this is a constructor, used for initializing an object.

More info on this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors

Comment: thanks a lot so you mean that I can make multiple new objects using the constructor in the given script?

Comment: That function will be called when you do the following in your code:

var parameters = new Parameters(); // a new Parameters object is initialized using the constructor you defined

Comment: Ah okay i think I get it you can use it for setting the values of the object which own the class i guess?

Comment: Yep, they are used to set default values and add behavior to an object initialization