# BankAccount' does not contain a definition for 'BankAccount

Tags: c#

This is bank account class:

```
namespace BankAccount
{
    public abstract class BankAccount
    {
        protected static int numberOfAccounts = 100001;
        private double balance;
        private string owner;
        private string accountNumber;

        public BankAccount()
        {
            balance = 0;
            accountNumber = numberOfAccounts + "";
            numberOfAccounts++;
        }

        public BankAccount(string name, double amount)
        {
            owner = name;
            balance = amount;
            accountNumber = numberOfAccounts + "";
            numberOfAccounts++;
        }

        public BankAccount(BankAccount oldAccount, double amount)
        {
            owner = oldAccount.owner;
            balance = amount;
            accountNumber = oldAccount.accountNumber;
        }
}
}
```

This is Checking account class:

```
namespace BankAccount
{
    class CheckingAccount : BankAccount
    {
        int fee = 15;
        public CheckingAccount(string name, double amount)
        {
           base.BankAccount(name, amount);
        }
        public new bool Withdraw(double amount)
        {
            double totalAmount = amount + fee;
            return base.Withdraw(totalAmount);
        }
    }
}
```

For, `base.BankAccount(name, amount);` I am getting error,

> 'BankAccount' does not contain a definition for 'BankAccount.'

Bank account is the base class and checking account inherits the base class.  and when I remove the base keyword it says:

> Non Invokable member cannot be used as a method.

In the main, I created an object, I want to accept a value in Main - a string and a double and then send it to `CheckingAccount` class and `CheckingAccount` constructor should run and then send the values to `BankAccount` constructor and do the calculations.

How can I fix the error

> 'BankAccount' does not contain a definition for 'BankAccount'

. ?
Thanks,

Comment: public CheckingAccount(string name, double amount)
                   :                base(name, amount) { }

Comment: Yeah, I am trying to Create an object for CheckingAccount:

CheckingAccount myCheckingAccount = new CheckingAccount("Benjamin Franklin", 1000);

and enter values into CheckingAccount constructor and then the values should be sent to BankAccount("Benjamin Franklin", 1000);

Comment: What exactly, do you think `base.BankAccount` does?

Comment: The entered values in Main should be sent into the CheckingAccount constructor and then to BankAccount Class Constructor.

Comment: @Daniel You should add that as an answer, not a comment

Comment: You need to read about how to call the base constructor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051/calling-the-base-constructor-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

C# Is not like Java where you call super() between the curly braces, you Need to add ' : base(name,Amout)' to call the super class constructor. Like this :

```
public CheckingAccount(string name, double amount) : base(name,amount)
{

}
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer and may add attract down votes. I would suggest to remove it before it gets down voted.

Comment: You are right, I was Just trying to help, I didn't read the whole constructor, saw the base at the end, I have edited my answer, I don't care about downvotes, I'm just here to help and share my experience and ideas.

Comment: I got you. And I believe everyone who is trying to solve the problem here has pretty much the same intention as you. Anyways right answer helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it in this way.

```
public CheckingAccount(string name, double amount) : base (name, amount)
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked